# Good avd settings for testing large screen devices with Android SDK?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'd like to test an application on a variety of screen configurations so I know that it'll work (and the layouts will look right) on tablets and other oddly sized devices. Does anyone have any tips or configuration settings that would be helpful?

Comment: Just search for the common ones and take a good subset of them. I personally only test on a 4 inch smartphone, a 7 inch tablet and a 10 inch tablet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (http://teavuihuang.com/android/) was exactly what I was looking for - a set of device AVD settings to emulate specific screen resolutions/densities.

Comment: Thanks for the alert. I should say that in the last 3 years, the Android SDK has come a long way, and there are many available emulators. Additionally, the price of tablets has plummeted, so the question is now pretty moot.

Answer (score 0):

you can create different virtual devices in eclipse using avd manager (window->sdk and avd manager). there are 6-7 type of devices with different resolutions varying from low to high.

Comment: Thanks, but what resolutions and display density should I use?